# awk condition on whether pattern is matched

Tags: awk, gsub

I am trying to have awk alter a given pattern if matched or return the original line. Here's my code

```
printf 'hello,"hru, bro"\nhi,bye\n' | gawk 'match($0, /"([^"]+)"/, m) {if (m[1] == "") {print $0} else {print gsub(/,/,"",m[1])}}'

-> 1
```

I expect `match to return the matched pattern in m[1] and gsub to substitute all ',' in m[1] when there is a match. Thus the result should be

```
-> hello,hru bro\nhi,bye
```

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE**

According to Tom comment I replace `gsub`with `gensub`, yet I now get the following result:

```
-> gawk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) warning: gensub: third argument `hru, bro' treated as 1
hello"hru, bro"
```

Comment: ok thanks, I should have checked the doc and use `gensub` instead. So I delete the question as its pretty dumb.

Comment: Actually it does not solve the problem., I have updated my post accordingly.

Comment: You are now passing the wrong arguments to gensub(), just like the warning message is telling you, but since you haven't shown us that code we can't tell you more than that.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to work with CSV files. They can be surprisingly tricky, as you're learning. I'd recommend working with a language that has a tested CSV library. Perl and Ruby spring to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gsub` mutates the third argument and returns the number of substitutions made - in this case, `1`.

I would suggest changing your code to something like this:

```
awk 'match($0, /([^"]*")([^"]+)(".*)/, m) { 
    $0 = m[1] gensub(/,/, "", "g", m[2]) m[3] 
} 1'
```

If there is anything surrounded by quotes on the line, then rebuild it, using `gensub` to remove the commas from the middle captured group (i.e. the part between the double quotes).

Note that `gensub` takes 4 arguments, where the third is used to specify the number of replacements to be made (`"g"` means *global*).